# Why can't I see the OS disk I just atached ?

Tags: azure

I just added a disk to my vm in azure :

[image]

But when I connect to my server and do a `df -h` I don't see it.
Should I mount something to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture, you don't have an additional disk in your VM. They appear as Data Disks. You only have the OS disk.

Assuming you have added a disk (attach new) and you are running Linux, check logs for it (no need to reboot):

```
$ sudo grep SCSI /var/log/messages
```

or

```
$ dmesg | grep SCSI
```

Then, initialize the disk and create partitions. Example:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
```

Format:

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

And finally mount it:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /datadrive
```

Ensure the disk is automatically mounted after a reboot:

```
$ sudo -i blkid

/dev/sdc1: UUID="33333333-3b3b-3c3c-3d3d-3e3e3e3e3e3e" TYPE="ext4"
```

Add it to fstab. Example:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/fstab

UUID=33333333-3b3b-3c3c-3d3d-3e3e3e3e3e3e   /datadrive   ext4   defaults,nofail   1   2
```

Please make sure to change every variable accordingly.

/sda - OS disk

/sdb - Temporary disk

/sdc-sdx - Should be your attached disks

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in this particular setup, but check if the disk needs to be initialized after it is mounted. This is the case in Hyper-V and other virtual engines.